# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null (click) in pure cordova project (without ionic) angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

where to add click EventListener? I am getting cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null.

```
export class BookConfirmComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
            console.log(""device is ready");    //this works
            document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
            console.log("button is clicked");     //Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Where is the associated html file?  Does the elementID of ```myBtn``` exist?

Comment: Yes element with ID myBtn exists in app.component.html. It has just this button.